# How can I get rid of a podcast?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I am desperately attempting to get rid of a podcast, but iTunes continues to resurrect it. The podcast I am trying to get rid of is the NBC Nightly News (Video).

These are the images of what it looks like when I am attempting to get rid of it:

1. In iTunes, it shows at unsubscribed.

[image]

[image]

2. In the iTunes store it shows as unsubscribed.

[image]

So, I should be able to simply delete it from iTunes and it should be gone. Right? Well, I select the podcast and press the delete key. It presents this dialog:

[image]

I select the delete option and it appears to be gone.

[image]

I then quit and restart iTunes and it comes right back again.

[image]

If I recheck the iTunes store, it still shows as unsubscribed.

Why? Why? Why?

What do I need to do to rid myself of this podcast? Any ideas?